# How can i add custom option menu icon Android

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, styles, icons

i want to add customs icons to my option menu, like that :

[image]

How can i do that with custom icons in my menu.xml ?

Or if you know the list of defaults icons, i am interested by that...

Here is my actual menu.xml code :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never" >
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/item1" android:title="Accueil" android:titleCondensed="Accueil" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_home"></item>
</menu>
```

Thanks !

Comment: Just google up and you'll find some tutorials like this one: [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-create-android-menus/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of the item tag, use `android:icon="@drawable/your_icon"`. That should work.